# Can any one help how to use Selenium Web Driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

In my scenario I have multiple classes using

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("userName")).SendKeys("jordan");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("54321" + Keys.Enter);
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(""));
```

When I execute the line

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(""));
```

I get Exception Error

**Source Code:**

```
<a class="hr" href="URL">
                        <div class="foo pixelated">
                            <img class="hr_resp" src="/Content/images/splash-images/icon_hr.png" style="margin-top:25px;">
                            <img class="hr_resp" src="/Content/images/splash-images/icon_hr_hub1.png" style="margin-top:25px;">
                        </div>
                        <p>Hr Managment</p>
                    </a>
```

Comment: Can you please add the detail question, no one of us will be able to answer question without any resources provided by you.

Comment: please consider reading the guidelines on asking a good question , you haven't provided enough info and you have assumed your urgency applies to others.

Comment: Would you please add more details? like what is programming  language you use and sample code that you are trying to execute it.

Comment: What is the error text? Without knowing what error you are getting there is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Error: Unable to locate element: hr

Comment: `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(""));` what does this line do.Try to comment this line. What is the exact error that you are getting. update the error in you questions description

Comment: In `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(""))`. In this you have not provided class name. So the element is not found. And be specific in writing the error. What error are you facing.

Comment: Just as an aside, you've got a typo in your source code -- 'Managment' should be 'Management'

Answer (score 3):

`driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(""))` - you need to provide a class name. Your argument is empty, obviously it cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have doubt about using the `driver.findElement(By.ClassName(//class name of the element))` please use the below link it's described how to find element using the class name

[Blog link-softwaretestingmaterial](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-locate-element-by-class-name-locator/)

[Git hub-seleniumhq.github](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByClassName.html)

> **Initially search your question if any other questions answers are
>   posted related to your asking question in before post your question.**

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try this :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));
```

If you use chrome, in the source code, right click on  the line `"<div class="foo pixelated">` and choose copy then copy XPath and paste it above.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I am not using but I am not using XPath

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment/delete this line **`driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(""));`** As I think it is not doing any thing in your code.

Before trying to find the element wait for it to get loaded.
You can do that by using

1. `Thread.sleep()` [Which is not advisable]
2. You can use WebDriverWait to check whether the element is loaded or not. Then do a `driver.findelement()`

Always ask question with all the relevant details or else others will not be able to help. Go through this link [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)